# Dropdown menu in angular select not picking up data

Tags: angular, webapi

error

```
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
    at ProductManagementComponent.search (product-management.component.ts:53)
    at ProductManagementComponent_Template_select_ngModelChange_0_listener (product-management.component.html:2)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15307)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.js:15351)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39)
    at EventEmitter_.emit (core.js:25968)
```

html = think i may have done something wrong here but cant find out why the data i select are not being sent

```
<select [(ngModel)]= "viewcat" name="pc.category" #pc.category ="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="search($event)">
        <option *ngFor = "let pc of productcategory" [ngValue] = "pc.category">
            {{pc.category|uppercase}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

viewcat = used to display data

```
public viewcat(){
    return this.httpclient.get("http://localhost:8094/api/ProductCategory");
  }
_____________________________________________________________
public viewcat(){
    this.productser.viewcat().subscribe((pc:{})=>{
      this.productcategory=pc;
      console.log(pc);
    });
  }
```

search = returns collection of the data being sent from html

```
 public search(form:NgForm){
    console.log("A");
    console.log(form.value.category);
    this.productser.search(form.value.category).subscribe((pc:{})=>{
      this.productcategory=pc;
      console.log(pc);
    });
  }
_____________________________________________________________
  public search(category:string){
    console.log(category);
    return this.httpclient.get(this.serverurl+"/"+category);
  }
```

Comment: How is your json structure which is returned from API?

Comment: `[
  {
    "category": "drink"
  },
  {
    "category": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "category": "veggie"
  }
]`
that is the data going into the viewcat

Comment: You have binded to ngModel in select and on value changes you are using form value, thats wrong. use ngModel variable and I dont think you are using reactive form , right?

Comment: nope just regular form

Comment: Then why are you using "form.value.category" in search method?

Comment: when the user selects one of the dropdown options itll call the search and pass the value into the search

Comment: To get the searched value use the property which you have binded in your select ngModel

Comment: `public search(form:(NgModel)){
    console.log("A");
    console.log();
    this.productser.search(form.value).subscribe((pc:{})=>{
      this.productcategory=pc;
      console.log(pc);
    });
  }` 
im getting undefined now am i passing it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding your select with `ngModel` that's mean you need to defined that variable in your component.

And after that in your model change event handler you can use that variable to get the select value and performed any action based on that.

```
<select [(ngModel)]= "category" name="category" (ngModelChange)="search($event)">
  <option *ngFor = "let pc of productCategory" [ngValue] = "pc.category">
      {{pc.category|uppercase}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Component Class Code:-

```
productCategory = [{
    category:'fruits'
  },
  {
    category:'animals'
}];
category: string;

search(event:any){
    console.log(this.category);
    //Rest of code
}
```

Working example:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fgaz8c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: [(ngModel)]= "viewcat" is calling a httpget to get the categories from db and storing it in the model right? then i want to user to be able to select a category from the dropdown and the selected will call another httpget to get a list of all the same categories from the db trying your method gave me a undefined as well but when i did this 
`public search(form:(NgModel)){
    console.log("A");
    console.log(form.value);
    this.productser.search(form.value).subscribe((pc:{})=>{
      this.productcategory=pc;
      console.log(pc);
    });
  }`
it gave me

Comment: `NgModel {_rawValidators: Array(0), _rawAsyncValidators: Array(0), _onDestroyCallbacks: Array(2), _parent: null, name: "category", …}`
also my html page was `<select [(ngModel)]= "viewcat" name="category" #category ="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="search($event)">
        <option *ngFor = "let pc of productcategory" [ngValue] = "category">
            {{pc.category|uppercase}}
        </option>
    </select>`

Comment: Try the sample code I have posted in that you can get the value.

Comment: hmmm it works but for some reason once i pick an option that option is only available until i refresh the page, how are yours able to change to other options after you selected one

Comment: What you mean by that, did not get your point.

Comment: so your select drop down once u select a option you are able to change to another option, when i select an option i am unable to pick a new option until i refresh the page

Comment: Its changing the value if you select any other option. Run above sample

Comment: yes i did but i used ur same logic onto my code but does not change ... once i pick an option the value is registered but i cannot pick another option ..

Comment: Please create a reproducible example to troubleshoot. it difficult to say without looking into your code. If you are following what I have describe above it should work.

Comment: nvm .... changed one variable and everthing fixed itself xd thanks

Comment: ok, Please accept the answer if this solves your problem.